# Correct Way to Use Dependency Injection - iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, dependency-injection, singleton

I have an object created in app delegate that I want to inject (dependency injection) into a specific class. My project setup is `TableViewController` -> when you select a cell it creates `PlayerViewController`. The project starts up on `TableViewController` so `window?.rootViewController?` is equal to that.

How would I pass the object created in app delegate directly to `PlayerViewController` on app launch? I believe this is not possible since at app launch `PlayerViewController` has not been created; so my solution is to pass the object first to `TableViewController` and then when you select a cell and create `PlayerViewController`, you pass the object again to it.

Is this the correct approach here?

**Note**:

- I am using Storyboards (so I pass data around with segues).
- I would like to avoid singletons if possible (unless it is the best approach here).

### Update 1:

**My main concern is this:**
`TableViewController` does not need the object but I pass the object to it because it acts as a bridge for me to then pass it to `PlayerViewController`. Is this good practice?

Comment: Your approach is what I have done. Avoiding singletons is a good idea for testability. I make an exception for a singleton class I wrote that applies fonts and colors to my UI controls, since passing that around became impractical.

Comment: @MikeTaverne Thanks for reply and glad I'm right track. I have a follow up, I updated my question - please take a look at the section "My main concern is this"

Comment: In my opinion that is fine.

Comment: Without any abstractions this is by far the easiest way to achieve what you do.